# Is this idiomatic Haskell - Two Sum Question

Tags: haskell

> Given a *list of integers* and a *target sum* determine whether there
>   is a pair of different numbers that sum to the *target sum*.

This is a classic LeetCode question and the solution I wrote consists of

1. Create an auxiliary *HashMap* that will let us determine whether we seen given number in previous iterations.
2. Iterate over every number:

   1. Check if `target_sum - current_number` is in the *HashMap*, if it is return True.
   2. Otherwise add the current_number to the *HashMap*.

O(n) time | O(n) space

I challenged myself to write this in Haskell and succeeded but not sure if this is idiomatic code. Please let me know.

```hs
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

twoSum :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
twoSum xs target_sum =
    let seen = Map.empty
    in twoSum' xs target_sum seen

twoSum' :: [Int] -> Int -> Map Int Int -> Bool
twoSum' [] target_sum seen = False
twoSum' (x:xs) target_sum seen
    | Map.lookup (target_sum - x) seen  /= Nothing = True
    | otherwise                                    = let new_seen = Map.insert x 0 seen
                                                     in twoSum' xs target_sum new_seen
```

Comment: It's not a hash map, it's tree-based. You should be using some form of set, not map. And similarly `Map.member` rather than `Map.lookup` because you only care whether an element exists and immediately throw away the information of what that element is. By moving the accumulating `seen` parameter to be the first argument, you can simplify the definition of `twoSum` with eta-reduction. Otherwise it's alright "basic" Haskell; ie. without busting out a `State` or even `Accum` monad. Oh and we typically camelCase variable names in Haskell.

Comment: This sort of question would be a better fit for code review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because better suited for coding review

Answer (score 2):

The time of this algorithm is strictly speaking *O(n log n)*, since the [**`insert`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:insert) is done in *O(log n)*.

It is a bit odd to use a `Map` here. What you here basically want to do is use a [**`Set`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set), since the value that you associate with the key here, does not really matter. This also removes the `Map.lookup ... /= Nothing` which is a bit "ugly": an `Integer` for example is indeed an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, but not types are members of the `Eq` typeclass, and thus checking with `(/=)` if something is not `Nothing`, requires the type wrapped in the `Maybe` to be a member of the `Eq` typeclass.

I think you here can simply first construct a set of values with `fromList`, and then check if there is any value `x` for which `target - x` differs from `x` and is part of this `Set`:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

twoSum :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
twoSum xs target = any (\x -> target - x /= x && S.member (target - x) mySet) xs
    where mySet = S.fromList xs
```

Comment: What if `target - x` is not a member of `mySet`..?

Comment: @Redu: well then the condition for that `x` is `False`, it checks if `any` element `x` from `xs` is a member. If none of the elements is, then it returns `False`.

Comment: Editing code is just fine but it should come with some responsibility of not discrediting previous comments.

Comment: @Redu: but your comment already says "What if `target - x` is not a member of `mySet`", so the "fix was already in the comment". The comment still stands (I think), and is answered by the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681248/is-this-idiomatic-haskell-two-sum-question/60681332?noredirect=1#comment107365014_60681332).

Comment: I think what @Redu means is that you edited the code in response to their comment and then wrote a response that could make it look like they had just missed something obvious.  "Well then" is ambiguous here.  Maybe, "Thanks, I fixed the problem.  Now,..." would have been clearer.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr: well I agree that there was a mistake in the answer. Thanks to Redu, I've spotted that, that is correct. I had the idea that the question was however more about what should happen if `target - x` is not a member of the set. But I might have misunderstood that. Thank you both! :)

Comment: `IntSet` would seem more appropriate than `Set Int`; it's much more efficient in typical cases.